# PHP Sort/Balance multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

everyone! Can someone help me with this problem? I have array of approximately 15.000 elements created randomly with the following structure:

```
<?php
$array = array(
    array(
        "id" => 134,
        "vertical_id" => 1
    ),   
    array(
        "id" => 52,
        "vertical_id" => 3
    ),   
    array(
        "id" => 334,
        "vertical_id" => 2
    ),   
    array(
        "id" => 123,
        "vertical_id" => 2
    ),   
    array(
        "id" => 153,
        "vertical_id" => 1
    ),   
    array(
        "id" => 176,
        "vertical_id" => 3
    ),   
    ...
);
```

_

I want to sort the array so the final result is something like this:

```
<?php
$array = array(
    array(
        "id" => 134,
        "vertical_id" => 1
    ),   
    array(
        "id" => 334,
        "vertical_id" => 2
    ),   
    array(
        "id" => 52,
        "vertical_id" => 3
    ),   
    array(
        "id" => 153,
        "vertical_id" => 1
    ),   
    array(
        "id" => 123,
        "vertical_id" => 2
    ),   
    array(
        "id" => 176,
        "vertical_id" => 3
    ),   
    ...
);
```

_

So if I do an array_slice I "guarantee" that I have the same amount of element for each vertical.

Any suggestions?

_

Comment: where's your attempted code?

Comment: Does the order of the `id` matter? Or does it just need to have `vertical_id` sorted as 1,2,3,1,2,3...?

Comment: @Don'tPanic the order of the ids do not matter, I just want to be sorted as 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3.. etc.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your question is not clear, do you want them to be sorted by id too, does the order of id matters?

Just to give you an idea, you need to write your own sorting function my_cmp() based on some logic (which ever key you want to be in ascending or descending order) and pass that my_cmp() function to usort.

For example,

```
function my_cmp($a, $b) 
    {
        // I'm sorting based on id field in ascending order
        return $a['id'] - $b['id'];
    }

usort($array1, "my_cmp");
```

For your given array, the above code will produce

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 52
            [vertical_id] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 123
            [vertical_id] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 134
            [vertical_id] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 153
            [vertical_id] => 1
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 176
            [vertical_id] => 3
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 334
            [vertical_id] => 2
        )

)
```

Just use this example and sort your array in whichever way you want. cheers !

Comment: the order of the ids do not matter, I just want to be sorted by the vertical_id as 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3.. etc

Answer (score 0):

First, you can convert the array into a multidimensional array with groups of items having the same `vertical_id`.

```
foreach ($array as $item) {
    $groups[$item['vertical_id']][] = $item;
}
```

Then sort the groups by key. Since we used `vertical_id` as the key of the outer array, this will ensure that the groups are in the correct order.

```
ksort($groups);
```

Then you can loop over the groups repeatedly, popping items off of them until one of them becomes empty, adding their items into a new array.

```
while (true) {
    // with each iteration of the foreach loop, you will get an item with vertical_id=1, 
    // vertical_id=2, and vertical_id=3 (in that order, because of the ksort.)
    foreach ($groups as &$group) { 
        // using a reference to $group because otherwise foreach will just make a copy
        if (!$group) break 2; // the 2 means it breaks out of the while loop 
        $sorted_array[] = array_pop($group); // add the item to the sorted array
    }
}
```

If you don't have an equal amount of items for each `vertical_id`, this will not use all of the items; it will just keep going until it runs out of items for one `vertical_id`.